# No me toma .js de Stripe [python-django]

Tags: python, django, stripe

Hola gente como andan? Estoy copiando el formulario que ofrece Stripe, y no me lee los archivos CSS ni JS.

Para los estilos no importa xq los puse con Bootstrap. Asique no habria problema, pero con Js si para que valide los datos.

En mi archivo Create.html es donde va mi formulario, este hereda de un archivo base.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block css %}
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/stripe.css' %}">
{% endblock %}
 
{% block content %}
  <div class="col">
    <div class="h3">
      Nuevo metodo de pago
    </div>

    <div class="">
          <form action="{% url 'billing_profiles:create' %}" method="post" id="payment-form">
              {% csrf_token %}
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-control" id="card-element" style="height:2.4em; padding-top:.7em">
                    <!-- stripe colocara los elemenos -->
                  </div>
                  <div class="" id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar nueva tarjeta</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block javascript %}
  <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
  <script scr="{% static 'js/stripe.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

y base.html es el siguiente: (CORTO EL  PARA AHORRAR CODIGO)

```
 </body>
    {% block javascript %}
    {% endblock %}
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/22d78598a5.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```

la carpeta static esta en la siguiente ruta:   ./static/js/stripe.js

Mi resultado es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Documentacion: https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes un error de tipeo al importar el archivo; dice `scr` cuando debiera decir `src`:

```
<script src="{% static 'js/stripe.js' %}"></script>
```

Comment: Me siento un ..... gracias!!

Comment: @gisela a quién no le ha pasado :D